# Chromebookにwsl2のXクライアントを表示する方法はありますか?

Tags: ssh, wsl, x11

Chromebook(Lenovo Ideapad duet)にwsl2のGUIを転送する方法を探しています。
お知恵を貸してください。また、同じようなことを試している方はいらっしゃいませんか?

事前に試したこと:
ChromebookのLinuxターミナルから、ラズパイにsshしてGUIを転送した[成功]
[chromebook] ssh -X [user_rasppi@IP]
[rasppi from chromebook] xeyes
のような感じです。ChromebookとLinuxの間ではGUIの転送ができることがわかりました。

ではwindowsマシン上のwsl2でのXアプリの画面は、Chromebookに表示できるのでしょうか?

やりたいこと:
wsl2上のXアプリを、Chromebookに転送する。

やりたいことについて試したこと:
chromebookからwindowsにssh -Y
↓
powershellを起動し $env:DISPLAY=[chromebookのIPアドレス:0.0]
↓
ssh -Y [wsl_username@localhost] (これでwslのターミナルを開けます)
↓
xeyesを実行すると以下のエラー
connect [chromebookのIPアドレス] port 6000: Connection refused
Error: Can't open display: localhost:10.0

なお、chromebookにおけるLinuxターミナルのポート6000番は開放してあります。

Comment: 「Chromebook から **直接** WSL 上の環境に SSH 接続」は試しましたか？

Comment: 「Chromebook 」でxhostを実行していますか？

Comment: 早速のコメントありがとうございます。WSLに直接SSHはまだ試していません。やってみます。

Comment: Chromebookでxhostはやっていません。ssh接続したwsl上でxhost +[chromebookのIPアドレス]としていましたがxhostについて誤解しているかもしれません。ChromebookのLinuxターミナル上でxhost +[wslのIPアドレス]とすればいいのでしょうか。試してみます。

Answer (score 1):

解決しました。
Chromebook ↔ Windows ↔ WSLの経路をポートフォワーディングすることで実現できました。

まずChromebookからWindowsに接続し、「WindowsからWSL(Windows上のlocalhost)」への経路を10022にポートフォワードします。

```
ssh [windows_user]@[windows_IP_address] -L 10022:localhost:22
```

Chromebookの別のターミナルから以下を実行します。

```
ssh -XC -p 10022 [wsl_user]@localhost
```

Comment: ご親切に、フォーマットを整えていただきまして、ありがとうございます